# WebBrowser click button failed with "onclick" if add document_click() in documentcompleted()

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

HTML is:

```
《a》 id="linkCreateOrder" class="btn_o140 btn_left"
onclick="SubmitCreateOrder();return false;"
href="javascript:void(3)">buy《a/》
```

Code is:

```
   void eb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_Click);
        }           
    }


    void Document_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.BubbleEvent = true;
        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElement htmlElement = htmlDocument.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);
        if (htmlElement.Id == "linkCreateOrder")
        {
            htmlElement.Style="background:#FF0000";
        }
    }
```

I have tried:

```
htmlelment.invokemember("click")，invokemember("onclick")

// and
htmldocument.invokescript("SubmitCreateOrder()");

// and
object obj = htmlElement.DomElement;
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("click");
mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```

None of these do what I need.

Comment: does Document_Click ever fires or this code fails HtmlElement htmlElement = htmlDocument.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);?

Comment: Thanks for your reply！！！！

Document_Click  fires successful。

HtmlElement htmlElement = htmlDocument.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition) is successful too.

But when I manual click the  href  《a id="linkCreateOrder" class="btn_o140 btn_left"
onclick="SubmitCreateOrder();    return false;"  href="javascript:void(3)" /a>   
nothing hapenned，hanged there！！！

Comment: and if I //webBrowser1.Document.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_Click); manual click the href is successful！！